# Jquery increase/decrease number in input text by up/down arrows keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a basic quantity field and would like to allow the user to increase/decrease the number within this input box based on the keyboard up/down.

Following on from: EndangeredMassa answer on keyboard code https://stackoverflow.com/a/375426/560287 how would I add this into a keyup function?

```
var keynum = 0;

if(window.event) { keynum = e.keyCode; }  // IE (sucks)
else if(e.which) { keynum = e.which; }    // Netscape/Firefox/Opera

if(keynum == 38) { // up
    //Move selection up
}

if(keynum == 27) { // down
    //Move selection down
}
```

Comment: have you looked at tangle.js? it has a really nice way of dealing with number fields

Comment: I think all you require now is this.value++ and this.value-- for up and down arrows respectively, you might need to use this.value = this.value.toInt()++.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
//cache our input since we will be working with it each time an arrow key is pressed
var $input = $('input');

//bind the the `keydown` event for the `document` object which will catch all `keydown` events that bubble up the DOM
$(document).on('keydown', function (event) {

    //up-arrow (regular and num-pad)
    if (event.which == 38 || event.which == 104) {

        //make sure to use `parseInt()` so you can numerically add to the value rather than concocting a longer string
        $input.val((parseInt($input.val()) + 1));

    //down-arrow (regular and num-pad)
    } else if (event.which == 40 || event.which == 98) {
        $input.val((parseInt($input.val()) - 1));
    }
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QRNP8/1/

Note that jQuery normalizes the `charCode`/`keyCode` properties into `event.which`:

> Query normalizes the following properties for cross-browser
>   consistency:
>
> ```
> target
> relatedTarget
> pageX
> pageY
> which
> metaKey
> ```

*Source: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/*

Comment: stop propogating the use of "=="! :P

Comment: @jbabey Actually I'm glad someone brought it up, what is the improvement? I get that triple equals will require the variable types to be the same but they perform the same...: http://jsperf.com/double-equals-vs-tripple-equals

Comment: using identity operators instead of equality forces you to write better code, at least in theory :P 

I would equate it to turning option strict on in VB.net/C# - it is good practice to use it all the time regardless of whether it would work the other way so that you avoid that fringe case that bites you in the butt.

Comment: I know this is super old, but just wondering how to make this only work if the input field is currently selected? At the moment, this will change the input field when someone is just using the arrows to scroll the page.
EDIT: Nevermind, as soon as I asked, it clicked! I wrapped it with $('input').focus(function() { // the rest here });

Answer (score 5):

Setting your input type to number will work as well. Though this won't work too great in IE9 and below.

```html
<input type="number">
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_number

Answer (score 2):

There's a small jQuery plugin for doing this: https://github.com/nakupanda/number-updown

Usages:

```
$('#textInput').updown();
```

View live demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/XCtaH/embedded/result/

Keyboard and mousewheel events supported

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
<input type="text" id="yourinput" value="0">

$(document).on("keypress", '*', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 38) { // up
        $('#yourinput').val(parseInt($('#yourinput').val(), 10) + 1);
    }

    if (e.keyCode == 40) { // down
        $('#yourinput').val(parseInt($('#yourinput').val(), 10) + 1);
    }
});
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/mSCBL/1/

Comment: I think you wanted to write
if (e.keyCode == 40) { // down
        $('#yourinput').val(parseInt($('#yourinput').val(), 10) - 1);
    }
in place of 
if (e.keyCode == 40) { // down
        $('#yourinput').val(parseInt($('#yourinput').val(), 10) + 1);
    }

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input").keypress(function(event) {
      var val=$(this).val();
      if ( event.keyCode== 38) {
          val++
         $(this).val(val)
      }
      if ( event.keyCode== 40) {
          val--
          $(this).val(val)
      };    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("something").keyup(function(e){
    var keynum = 0;

    if(window.event) { keynum = e.keyCode; }  // IE (sucks)
    else if(e.which) { keynum = e.which; }    // Netscape/Firefox/Opera

    if(keynum == 38) { // up
       //Move selection up
    }

    if(keynum == 27) { // down
       //Move selection down
    }
});
```

Where `something` is a selector which matches your input(s).

Comment: jQuery normalizes the which property so that it works cross browser i think

Comment: Fair enough.  Wasn't really looking at the code itself, more showing how to stick it in a `keyup`.

Answer (score 0):

Your codes looks correct-ish. If your just wondering how to bind the code to the event...

```
$('#itemId').keyup(function(e){ 
    /*YOUR CODE*/  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
if(keynum == 38) { // up
    this.value = parseInt(this.value)-1;
}

if(keynum == 27) { // down
    this.value = parseInt(this.value)+1;
}
```